# Solr query that only matches when 2 values are together with no other values on a multivalued field

Tags: solr

A query like this:

```
&q=im_field_teams:(4667 AND 4675)
```

Will return results like this:

```
docs: [
{
  im_field_teams: [
    4675,
    4667
  ]
},
```

Which is great! However of course I also get values like this:

```
{
  im_field_teams: [
    4660,
    4702,
    4675,
    4667,
    4684,
  ]
}
```

Which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

I want an "ONLY AND" or AND AND NOT * or something like that. Matching documents that include only a pair of values (no more, no less) in a multivalued field.

(For what it's worth this: seems to work but feels really wrong.)

```
&q=im_field_teams:(4667 AND 4675) -im_field_teams:[0 TO 4666] -im_field_teams:[4668 TO 4674] -im_field_teams:[4676 TO *]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this. But there are workarounds/ possible options that can be done (see below), but with possibly simpler query syntax. The query with negation can get tricky sometimes if we have overlapping ranges and with multiple AND clauses.

During index add another field with the size of the array in the multi valued field. Say for example if a document has (4660,    4702,    4675,    4667,    4684) then this field will have size of 5. In Query time, include this field depending on how many entries you are adding. In this case if you are searching for `q=im_field_teams:(4667 AND 4675)` then add another clause `AND im_field_teams_size:2` condition. This will ensure that all terms are matched and **only** those.